# Get Column's Custom Type Name SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, types

I'm trying to get the custom type name: `UUID` for a column in an SQLite table using a ResultSet but I can't figure out any way to do this. I tried using ResultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName() but this doesn't seem to work.

Based on the ResultSetMetaData docs, it seems like it should:

> Returns: type name used by the database. If the column type is a user-defined type, then a fully-qualified type name is returned.

But the method types returns `null` if the column has no data, and `text` if it does.

Is there any other way to do this without having to do a second query every single time using PRAGMA table_info? I also don't have a reference to the table name at this point (just the ResultSet) so that would be difficult.

Comment: Isn't everything type text in SQLite?

Comment: There is no `UUID` type in SQLite http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: There are numerous types in SQLite. The UUID is a string and `text` is the type of the value. I'm trying to retrieve the *type name* that I assigned to column, which is `UUID`

Comment: I just tried `ResultSetMetaData#getColumnTypeName` with sqlite-jdbc-3.18.0.jar and it returned "UUID" for me when I did "SELECT * FROM table1". Code [here](https://pastebin.com/uRkN6CvJ).

Comment: @GordThompson agghh thank you. I was using a very outdated version of the driver :(